# MYSQL duplicates when using ->insert_id

Tags: mysql, insert-id

I was happy when I got this to work but it submits the order twice unless I comment out the last two lines. Is there a better way to write it so that I don't get duplicates?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (weight, shipper, shipacct) VALUES ('$weight', '$shipper', '$shipacct')";
$conn->query($sql);
$recordid = $conn->insert_id;
```

I did this this way because I'm trying to use the record ID as the order ID. I echo this order ID back to the customer on the purchase receipt.

updated code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (weight, shipper, shipacct) VALUES ('$weight', '$shipper', '$shipacct')";
$recordid = mysql_insert_id();
```

no duplicates, but does not return the record ID.

Comment: `$conn->query($sql);` is the line that actually runs the query.  How is this code being called?  You may be calling it twice, or posting the form twice, or using a loop or something.

Comment: Unexpected places to check if the code is called twice:  Do you have rewrite rules which perform a redirection?  Do you have any `<img>` or `<link>` or similar tags which mistakenly have empty `src=` attributes, causing them to request the same URL twice?

Comment: Just incase: I think your query might be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. [Take a look here](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: I got rid of the $conn line, and it stopped inserting duplicates. The $recordid line though does not return the record ID. It comes back blank when using $recordid = mysql_insert_id();

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**

```
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.
Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information.
Alternatives to this function include:
mysqli_insert_id()
PDO::lastInsertId()
```

Try the following:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (weight, shipper, shipacct) VALUES ('$weight', '$shipper', '$shipacct')";
$conn->query($sql);
$recordid = mysql_insert_id();
```

**Note:**
Because mysql_insert_id() acts on the last performed query, be sure to call mysql_insert_id() immediately after the query that generates the value.

Hopefully, [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) and [this](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10346283-RESOLVED-putting-value-of-mysqli-insert_id-into-a-variable) will help...